# Assert array in ParameterFilter for Pester Assert-MockCalled

Tags: powershell, unit-testing, pester

We are trying to assert a call with specific parameter which is an array and it's returning **false** in **Assert-MockCalled**, for all other parameters which are not array it's working (string types).

Here is my example:

```
function NewZip ($Name) {
    $compress = @{
        Path             = "$PSScriptRoot/terms.txt", "$PSScriptRoot/fav.ico"
        CompressionLevel = "Fastest"
        DestinationPath  = "$PSScriptRoot/$Name.zip"
    }

    Compress-Archive @compress -Update
}

It "Creates a zip file" {
    # Arrange
    $name = "test"
    $assertParams = @{
        CommandName     = 'Compress-Archive'
        Times           = 1
        ParameterFilter = { 
            $Path -in "$PSScriptRoot/terms.txt", "$PSScriptRoot/fav.ico" -and
            $DestinationPath -eq "$PSScriptRoot/$name.zip" -and
            $CompressionLevel -eq  "Fastest" -and
            $Update -eq $true
        }
    }

    Mock Compress-Archive {}

    # Act
    NewPackage -Name $name

    # Assert
    Assert-MockCalled @assertParams
}
```

How can I use array comparison within Assert-MockCalled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> $Path -in "$PSScriptRoot/terms.txt", "$PSScriptRoot/fav.ico"
> ```

can't work [because](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#-in-and--notin):

> When the test object is a set, these operators use reference equality to check whether one of the set's elements is the same instance of the test object.

You can use [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7.1) instead to do a value comparison:

```
ParameterFilter = { 
    -not (Compare-Object $Path "$PSScriptRoot/terms.txt", "$PSScriptRoot/fav.ico") -and
    $DestinationPath -eq "$PSScriptRoot/$name.zip" -and
    $CompressionLevel -eq  "Fastest" -and
    $Update -eq $true
}
```

The negation is required because `Compare-Object` outputs the differences. It outputs nothing if the arrays are equal. When captured, "nothing" turns into `$null` which converts to `$false` in a boolean context.

The parentheses (aka [group operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#grouping-operator--)) are required in order to use the output of `Compare-Object` in an expression.

Comment: Sorry, but that is not even compiling :( I'm wondering how to use that within `Assert-MockCalled`

Comment: @DAG You are right, I've fixed the code and show how to use it as part of your original code.

Comment: Thanks, it's compiling now, but it always returns `$true` .For example if you change `terms.txt` to `terms2.txt` the test still is green.

Comment: @DAG It works for me. When I change it like this, the test fails as expected. PS 7.1.3, Pester 5.1.0.

Comment: It works indeed. I had a small typo :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one! I spent most of a day on this.

This was failing:

```
Mock Invoke-MyFunc { } -Verifiable -ParameterFilter { $realArray -eq $testArray }
```

because as the answers above detail, you can't compare arrays this way.

I ended up with:

```
Mock Invoke-MyFunc { } -Verifiable -ParameterFilter { (Compare-Object $realArray $testArray).length -eq 0 }
```

Because if the length is zero, the arrays are equal, and we need to return a `boolean` in the ParameterFilter.